# angular ng-route : undefined route nesting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I want to route to all child paths to m.

```
.state('index.m', {
        url: "m",
        views: {
            "viewContainer": {
                templateUrl: "p/m.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

Thus /m and /m/123  and /m/123/a all map to the same route `index.m`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [URLMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type%3aUrlMatcher) format:

```
.state('index.m', {
        url: "m{path:.*}",
        views: {
            "viewContainer": {
                templateUrl: "p/m.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

This should match anything that starts with m.

Comment: the template gets reloaded i don't want that to happen.